# LINQ Except/Distinct based on few columns only, to not add duplicates

Tags: c#, .net, linq, distinct, except

Excuse me for the confusing title. But I couldn't come up with something more simpler.

I have got below class.

```
public class Foo
{
    public FooId int { get; set; }

    public FooField string { get; set; }

    //some more fields here....
    //....
    //....

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I need to loop through something and add a range of `Foo` to a `List<Foo>`, but it should not be duplicate based on the combination of `FooId` and `FooField`.

So I am trying as below

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();

foreach (Bar item in blah.Bars)
{
    //Some code here to get the foos from the item
    List<Foo> processedFoos = item.GetFoos();

    //The problem is with below line
    foos.AddRange(processedFoos.Except(foos));
}
```

The `Except` adds all the records and duplicates the `FooId` and `FooField` combination as `CreatedDate` would be unique for all records.

But I need to ignore the `CreatedDate` and just add those records which does not violate the unique combination.

What can I do here? `Except`? `Distinct`? Any other alternative?

Most important, how?

Comment: implement `IEqualityComparer<Foo>` and use the appropriate overload of the `Except()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb336390(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You either need to override `Equals` in `Foo`, or implement an `IEqualityComparer<Foo>` so that `Except` can tell when two `Foo` values are equal. For example:

```
public sealed class FooComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        return x.FooId == y.FooId && x.FooField == y.FooField;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo foo)
    {
        // Note that if FooField can be null, you'll need to account for that...
        return foo.FooId ^ foo.FooField.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
 foos.AddRange(processedFoos.Except(foos, new FooComparer()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `Except` and `Distinct` will compare items based on the object's `Equals` implementation (this is the default equality comparer).  They also both have overloads that take an `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

You could implement this interface (see [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an example) comparing only the fields you require and pass it to `Except`:

```
 foos.AddRange(processedFoos.Except(foos, comparer));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the way how you select not duplicated records:

```
processedFoos.Where(x => !foos.Any(y => y.FooId == x.FooId && y.FooField == x.FooField))
```

Comment: I think it is a better solution rather than except

Answer (score 1):

`Except` and `Distinct` both have an overload that takes an `IEqualityComparer`. You can implement one to compare only  the properties you need.

An alternative is to group by FooId and FooField and take the first element from each group:

```
processFoos.GroupBy(foo => new {foo.FooId, foo.FooField})
.Select(g => g.First());
```

Comment: `GroupBy().Select()` approach is good, but it gets distinct `processedFoos` based on the unique combination. And I need to check for duplicates in `processedFoos` which are already not there in `foos`. Thank you for your answer. Appreciated! I am going to implement `IEqualityComparer`, as you and others have suggested and @Jon Skeet has demonstrated in his answer.